# List topics and their configuration with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, command-line-interface, aws-msk

Is it possible to use the AWS CLI tool to list the Kafka MSK topics and display the configuration of them?

Comment: I haven't used Kafka, but looking at [kafka — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/kafka/index.html), it appears that the API calls are "operations for managing an Amazon MSK cluster" rather than interacting with Kafka itself.

Comment: Doesn't the MSK documentation show you how to list topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **Kafka native Java API**. Please check [how to use kafka](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/kafka-list-topics#listing-topics) on its own, before you start using MKS.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the AWS MSK service (therefore the APIs exposed by the AWS CLI) is for setting up and managing the Kafka cluster. But the actual interactions with the cluster still happen via Kafka Admin tooling.

MSK provides a quick start guide which takes you through setting up a client EC2 machine, downloading the Kafka binaries, and using the tools in the binaries to create a topic.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/create-client-machine.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/create-topic.html

I would recommend reviewing that basics guide, and then reviewing a bit more of the Kafka documentation about what other configurations and mutations are available via the Kafka CLI Tools.

Comment: what if I don't want to create an ec2 client. is there a way I can create a topic by running a kafka library script in the same vpc using a lambda?